# Codeigniter: set_message unable to work

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my controller code:

```
public function login_validation(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('model_users');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|alpha_numeric|xss_clean|strip_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
            if ($this->model_users->can_log_in()){
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                );

                if($this->model_users->get_status($data['username'])){
                    $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'privilege' => 'member',
                    'is_logged_in' => 1
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect('member');
                } else {
                    $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'privilege' => 'admin',
                    'is_logged_in' => 1
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect('admin');
                }
            } else {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('login_validation', 'Incorrect username/password.');
            }
        } else {
            $this->login();
        }
```

May i know why does the `$this->form_validation->set_message('login_validation', 'Incorrect username/password.');` doesn't work when the user credentials are entered incorrectly? I tried it and the result was that it will result an empty blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You can view all errors with:

> $message = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() :
>   $this->session->flashdata('message');
>
> var_dump($message);

And you need activate the log-

Edit the file: application/config/config.php
 - Full/All error reporting, set it to 4.
 - For only ERRORS,set it to 1.
 - For ERRORS and WARNINGS/DEBUG,set it to 2.

Then Set CodeIgniter log directory to be writable by the server, use command:

> chmod 777 /logs/

Now you are ready to get logs in your log file.That from command line you can do as:

> tail -f /application/logs/log-YYYY-MM-DD.php

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, what i meant was that i want to display the error to the user that they have enter either the wrong username or password on my website.